# How to parse JSON in PowerApps?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have stored JSON data in SharePoint online list multi line and text column. I need to update that column in Power Apps form.

Can anyone help me for how to parse / stringfy the JSON data in Power Apps without using Flow?

Thanks & Regards,
Meet

Answer (score 1):

You can use Power Automate to parse JSON string to Object. Action is named "Parse JSON".

Serializing from Object to string is possible using **JSON** function in PowerApps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-json

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you will have to use Power Automte/flow for converting string to Json. Out of box canvas App does not have any method to convert string to json. The closet you can get is [JSON function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-json).

[Here is nice article of Power Apps (canvas App) with power automate to convert string to JSON](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2020/05/how-to-pass-power-apps-collection-in-power-automate-using-json-function/)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use MatchAll() to do much of the parsing.  Issue is getting the correct RegEx string (in PowerApps format) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Today Microsoft has provided the function to parse the JSON inside the powerapps itself. It is an experimental feature for now. You can learn more from here:
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-fx-introducing-parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

Power Apps now supports experimental **ParseJSON** function which might be helpful to you.

Check below links for detailed information:

1. [Power Fx: Introducing ParseJSON](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-fx-introducing-parsejson/)
2. [ParseJSON function in Power Apps (experimental)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-parsejson)